# Rails 5 API only creating records from nested attribute arrays

Tags: schema, nested-attributes, rails-api

I am new to Rails and am wondering what the proper "Rails way" is to handle the following situation. The application I am working on is a Rails api-only backend with a ReactJS front end. In my schema I have three models that are associated in various ways (more on that in a bit): Composer, Album, Track. In the client I create an object that looks roughly like this:

```
{
  composer: {
    name: 'Foo',
    other_info: 'Blah Blah',
    albums: [
      {
        title: 'Album 1',
        tracks: [
          {
            title: 'Track 1',
          }, 
          {
            title: 'Track 2',
          },
        ]
      }, 
      {
        title: 'Album 2',
        tracks: [
          {
            title: 'Track 1',
          },
          {
            title: 'Track 2',
          },
        ]
      },
    ]
  }
}
```

**The associations are as follows:**

- Composers and Albums are associated with the `has_many through` relation(Composers can have many albums and albums can have many composers).
- Album `has_many` tracks, and each track `belongs_to` a single album.
- Composer `has_many` tracks and each track `belongs_to` a single composer.

It is easy for me to `update` Composer, Album, or Track records because I already have the `id` and that seems to be handled automatically by Rails. (Cool!)

My question is this:

**Is there a way to send the object above in a `POST` request that will parse out the Albums and tracks where I can set the proper associations?**

My naive method (which I was in the process of setting up on the Client... and I *really* don't want to do that kind of business logic there) ends up as the following:

1. Create the `Composer` record and `POST` to Rails API.
2. Create the `Album` record and `POST` to Rails API.
3. Create all of the `Track` records and `POST` to Rails API.
4. Update each `Track` with the Composer and Album ids.
5. Update the `Album` to be associated to the `Composer`.

I would *much* rather handle all of that in the API. (Especially because I need to handle situations where the `Album` already exists and needs to be *updated* as opposed toe *created*.)

So in essence, I am hoping that the client just has to submit the object with nested entities as it is above, then I do all of the work setting up new `Composer`, `Album`, and `Track` records and associations on the back end.

Is that doable or even recommended? And if so I could really use a good source of documentation or a tutorial on how this situation is handled. My search skills have failed to yield up anything that seems like it addresses this issue.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out the solution was simple, although my schema was going to be way too difficult to implement. Having *both* the tracks *and* albums associated with composers was too much trouble, so I nixed that idea.
I discovered that I was using `:albums` and `:tracks` instead of `:albums_attributes` and `:tracks_attributes`. That change makes all of the association magic happen automatically.